# What's the difference between ':source file' and ':runtime file' in vim?

Tags: vim

I saw this command in the `/etc/vimrc` file on my system:

```
runtime! vimrc_example.vim
```

From the docs:

> :ru[ntime][!] {file} ..
>                           Read Ex commands from {file} in each directory
>   given
>                           by 'runtimepath'.

Is it otherwise equivalent to `:source {file}`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`:source` sources the file specified by the path given (relative or absolute)

`:runtime` sources the first file (unless banged!) found in `&runtimepath` that matches the partial path given.

BTW, the pathnames used with `:runtime` can contain wildchars (somehow a glob-pattern). This has nothing to do with regexes.