# What is the difference between vimrc and vimruntime

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I downloaded the vimrc from [amix/vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) which is very helpful for starting out in vim. But as I try to edit the .vim_runtime I keep getting errors. Here is my .vimrc

```
set runtimepath+=~/.vim_runtime
    source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/basic.vim
    source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/filetypes.vim
    source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/plugins_config.vim
    source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/extended.vim
 try
    source ~/.vim_runtime/my_configs.vim
 catch
 endtry
```

Now I wanted to change the settings for my NERDTree plugin but I don't know where to edit my setting. The configuration is confusing to a new person to vim. I found this similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321073/whats-the-difference-between-source-file-and-runtime-file-in-vim) but it doesn't doesn't help in my endevour. Can someone explain the difference between the vimrc and vimruntime? I can see that the vimrc grabs the settings from the .vim_runtime but do I add settings to vimrc or vimruntime? Which one is the best place to add settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using someone else Vim config files which is a can be a bit tricky, especially when the `vimrc` file is large or broken up into many files.

#### What's going on here?

amix has decided to break up his `vimrc` config into smaller files to help organize his `vimrc` file. He has done this by `:source`-ing these files form his `vimrc` file (See `:h :source`). Now in theory you can add your NerdTree setting inside one of these other files, probably `~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/plugins_config.vim`.

It should be noted that this file convention is *not* native Vim, just something that amix has invented to help him deal with a sprawling `vimrc` file. His conventions may not line up with your own organization and may hinder if you seek help in the future.

#### A friendly warning

There are a few thing to note about young vimmers using other's configuration files:

- Often using a large and/or complex vimrc will lead confusion when you want to make your own customizations
- A vimrc file is a very opinionated file. Your opinions may clash
- Assumpting that the vimrc your copied is "good" or more likely: "good for *your* workflow"
- Often many settings are simply copied without any understanding. Good example is the `'gdefault'` option (See `:h 'gdefault'`)
- Copying without understanding can lead to [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)
- Vimrc files are prone to cruft. This means you are probably copying things that aren't being used anymore, are confusing, or just plain broken

#### Thoughts

It is often best to start with a small vimrc file and slowly add to it as you learn. This means you understand every line in your vimrc. A good place to start with your vimrc is: [idiomatic-vimrc](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc).

For general Vim customization advice I will point you to Drew Neil's Vimcast post: [On sharpening the saw](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2012/08/on-sharpening-the-saw/)

For more information see:

```
:h vimrc-intro
:h vimrc_example.vim
:h vimrc
:h startup
:h :source
:h 'gdefault'
```

Comment: Great answer very helpful and direct! Thank you for the advice I do not disagree, I was hoping to get a jump into a working text editor so that I would enjoy using it and thus work in it more frequently. Maybe a little too eager..